# L1 + L2 cache hardware information with lscpu different to information from Intel & Windows

Tags: 14.04, kernel, 14.10, cpu

My CPU is an INTEL Celeron N2930 Bay Trail-M 1.83GHZ to (2.16GHZ Turbo)

I get by typing lscpu in Terminal a different value of L1 + L2 Cache (Hardware Information) in comparison to the Intel + Windows info. The L1 Cache under Ubuntu 14.04.1 is 56KB and L2 Cache is 1024 KB. Original posted on the Intel website is L1=224KB / L2=2048KB and also in the Windows Task Manager.

the output for: `lscpu` is:

```
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                4
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-3
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    4
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 55
Stepping:              8
CPU MHz:               1328.000
BogoMIPS:              3666.81
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             24K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              1024K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-3
```

The Maximum CPU Speed under Ubuntu 14.04.1 is 1.83GHZ. Is my CPU Linux friendly?

Why is the difference in L1+L2 Cache. I tested the unicorn Kernel with same results.

Comment: can you post the full output of lscpu?

Comment: I've postet the lscpu output. Thank's for help!

Answer (score 0):

OK, I compared it to my processor and your processor has two memory channels and mine too, so you have to multiply (or divide) the cache by the number of memory channels, so that's solved!

The *maximum* CPU is not dependent on Ubuntu but on your motherboard/chipset/RAM,… Also, Ubuntu lowers the CPU speed automatically if you're not using it a lot to save energy!  ;)

The Level1 cache stumps me too: no explanation.  (Ask Intel and report back here)

And most important of all: **Yes, your processor is Ubuntu-friendly!**  ;)

Comment: Thank you very much! I will check it by Intel. Hope i will get a clear answer...

Comment: I got a fast answer from Intel. L1d=24K + L1i=32K = Total 56K Cache / Core. My Processor has 4 Cores: 56K*4Cores = Total 224K. So simple is it.

Comment: Can you accept my answer as correct then?  Gives me some extra points on my reputation!  ;)